# Conditional class in *NgFor with angular

Tags: angular, html, angular-template

I have this html code:

```
 <div class="chip-idiomas">
    <mat-chip-list multiple [selectable]="true">
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let idioma of idiomas"
                class="chip"
                [ngClass]="{'chip-selecionado' : isClassVisible}"
                [selected]="idioma"
                (click)="isClassVisible = !isClassVisible;changeSelected('s', idioma)">
        {{ idioma.nome }}
      </mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
  </div>
```

When I click on the chip, the class change in all , not just in the chip clicked. I'm using Angular 5.

I wish just the clicked element changed the css

See this pic before and after

**before**:
[image]

**after**:
[image]

can Someone help?

Comment: It looks like your property used to distinguish those is a class level property (`isClassVisible`). You will need to have a property on each element in the `*ngFor` that states for this element what the `isClassVisible` value is. i.e. `idioma.isClassVisible` instead of just `isClassVisible`

Comment: Share your ts file

Comment: Specifically, please show us `changeSelected()` (when the element is `(click)`ed a function is called, but and that's the problem, but you didn't show us the function :)), any class members it writes to, and your CSS. That said, Daniel is certainly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:-

Stackblitz Link:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-jyzotv?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

```
 <div class="chip-idiomas">
    <mat-chip-list multiple [selectable]="true">
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let idioma of idiomas;let isFirst = first"
                  [selected]="tab === idioma"
                  class="chip"
                 [class.active]="tab === idioma"
               (click)="activateClass(idioma)">
        {{ idioma }}
      </mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
  </div>

  <div class="chip-idiomas">
    <mat-chip-list multiple [selectable]="true">
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let idioma of idiomas;let isFirst = first"
                  class="chip"
                 [class.active]="tab === idioma"
               (click)="activateClass(idioma)">
        {{ idioma }}
      </mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
  </div>
```

--

```
export class AppComponent  {
  idiomas = ['A','B','C']
  tab = this.idiomas[0];

  activateClass(subModule){
  this.tab = subModule;    
}
}
```

Comment: Let me know if any issue you have.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to store `index` in `isClassVisible` and rename it to something like `visibleClassIndex`, and check in `[ngClass]` if current class is visible by checking current `index` with `visibleClassIndex`, since there will be `0` index, which is `false` value, I would suggest you to define `visibleClassIndex` type as `null | number` or `undefined | number` and do check like so `visibleClassIndex !== null && visibleClassIndex === i` or `visibleClassIndex !== undefined && visibleClassIndex === i`, if you will choose `null` make sure to assign `null` as default value `visibleClassIndex: null | number = null;`, I would suggest to use `undefined`, because with it you don't need to define default type, since it automatically will be `undefined`

```
 <div class="chip-idiomas">
    <mat-chip-list multiple [selectable]="true">
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let idioma of idiomas"
                class="chip"
                [ngClass]="{'chip-selecionado' : visibleClassIndex !== undefined && visibleClassIndex === i}"
                [selected]="idioma"
                (click)="visibleClassIndex = i;changeSelected('s', idioma)">
        {{ idioma.nome }}
      </mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
  </div>
```